# Почему возникает ошибка TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.?

Tags: javascript

Вот собственно код:

```
"function(file,dataUrl){var date = new Date(); var path =  window.location.host+'/frontend/web/image/page/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/'+file.name;var img='<img src=\"'+path+'\" />'; document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img[0]);}"
```

Кавычки вначале и конце кода собственно нужны потому что использую js в php плагине вот разбил по строкам.

```
function(file,dataUrl){
    var date = new Date(); 
    var path =  window.location.host+'/frontend/web/image/page/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/'+file.name;
    var img='<img src=\"'+path+'\" />';     
    document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img[0]);}
```

пытался и так

```
function(file,dataUrl){
    var date = new Date(); 
    var path =  window.location.host+'/frontend/web/image/page/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/'+file.name;
    var img='<img src=\"'+path+'\" />';     
    document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img)[0];}
```

Эффект тот же.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так

```js
function(file,dataUrl){
    var date = new Date(); 
    var path =  window.location.host+'/frontend/web/image/page/'+date.getFullYear()+'/'+(1+date.getMonth())+'/'+file.name;
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = path;
    document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img)[0];
}
```

Comment: `[0]` - не нужен

Answer (score 2):

Здесь собирается строка

```
var img='<img src=\"'+path+'\" />';
```

Далее у нее берется первый символ `img[0]`, либо идет попытка вставить ее как строку.

Вместо этого можно создать сам элемент `img`, с помощью [функции createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), присвоить созданному элементу src, и добавить его, например так

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = path;
document.getElementById('forIMG').appendChild(img)
```